# Getting user access token for currency

Tags: php, facebook, currency, facebook-access-token

While integrating local currency payments to our app, we need to retrieve the users prefered currency, so that we can display the prices in our app.

The app is running on the php sdk.

However, it seems that in order to get the prefered currency, we need a users access token.

I am unable to figure out how we can retrieve this.
Could someone point me in the right direction

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
$facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

will return "oauth_token", for the given user. With that it should be easy to get data from the graph